# Does array element contain substring?

Tags: php, arrays, string, contains

I'd like a function that checks whether an array's items *contain* a string.
As such:

```
array(1 => 'Super-user', 'Root', 'Admin', 'Administrator', 'System', 'Website', 'Owner', 'Manager', 'Founder');
```

And then checking for `admin12` should return true as a part of `admin12` (`admin`) is also a part of the array.

I came this far:

```
$forbiddennames= array(1 => 'Super-user', 'Root', 'Admin', 'Administrator', 'System', 'Website', 'Owner', 'Manager', 'Founder');    

if(in_array( strtolower($stringtocheck), array_map('strtolower', $forbiddennames))){
        echo '"This is a forbidden username."';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Only this only echos "This is a forbidden username." when I check for `admin`. I want it also to echo when checking for `admin12`.

Is this possible (and how)?

Comment: I don't think this is much of a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words - an array of string definitely has different qualities than just a string, and I'm looking into doing this with a regexp. How can one object to this "marked as duplicate"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop through the `$forbiddennames` array and use `stripos` to check if the given input string matches *any* of the items in the array:

```
function is_forbidden($forbiddennames, $stringtocheck) 
{
    foreach ($forbiddennames as $name) {
        if (stripos($stringtocheck, $name) !== FALSE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like below:

```
if(is_forbidden($forbiddennames, $stringtocheck)) {
    echo "This is a forbidden username.";
} else {
    echo "True";
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/57770)

Comment: This allows "admin12" to echo true, while I want it to echo "this is a..." because "admin12" (input) contains "Admin" (from the f.n. array).

Comment: @Isaiah: That was a minor mistake from my part. I accidentally switched the parameters for `stripos()`. Please see the updated answer (and the [demo](https://eval.in/57770))

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($forbiddennames as $forbiddenname) {
    $nametocheck = strtolower($stringtocheck);
    if(strpos($stringtocheck, $forbiddenname) !== false) {
        echo "This is a forbidden username.";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check for !==, as strpos could also return 0 if a match is found

Comment: Yep, absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter if you use array_map, foreach or something different. Possible solution:

```
$forbiddenNames = array('admin', 'bannedName');
$input = 'Admin12';
$allowed = true;
foreach($forbiddenNames as $forbiddenName) {
    if(stripos($input, $forbiddenName) !== false) {
        echo $input, ' is invalid';
        $allowed = false;
        break;
    }
}
if($allowed === true) {
    echo $input, ' is valid';
}
```

Comment: Works as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you want PHPs 'strpos' function. loop through each array element, and then check each element against 'strpos' [PHP strpos reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
foreach($forbiddennames as $fn){
 if(strpos($stringtocheck,$fn)){
  //found it!
 }else{
  //not found!
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you go through the entire array, if there is the possibility to break after an invalid name is found?

Comment: 'strripos' is better if you want case-insensitive search. I would use it over 'strpos', but the code sample would basically be the same

Comment: @ChrisWesson: That's different. I think you meant `stripos()` (with one `R`) :)

Comment: word. one 'r'. thanks!